# Llamar a la función ReadAsMultipartAsync() de manera síncrona

Tags: c#

Utilizo Navision para llamar a la función `ReadAsMultipartAsync().Result` desde una librería en C#, pero bloquea Navision. Si en la librería utilizo await y sync, no puedo gestionar el resultado (Task) desde Navision.
Si hago `streamCont.ReadAsMultipartAsync(provider).Wait(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20));` funciona, pero espera de 20 segundos.
¿Hay alguna manera de llamar a la función `ReadAsMultipartAsync()` de manera síncrona?

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! la respuesta corta es no.. si la funcion dice Async, es para llamarla async...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

He encontrado una forma de hacerlo que funciona.
Es curioso pero esto **bloquea** Nav:

```
Task<MultipartMemoryStreamProvider> task = streamContent.ReadAsMultipartAsync();
task.Wait();
```

Y estas dos funcionan bien:

```
Task thread1 = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => result = streamContent.ReadAsMultipartAsync().Result);
Task.WaitAll(thread1);
```

```
Task tarea1 = new Task(() => result = streamContent.ReadAsMultipartAsync().Result);
tarea1.Start();
tarea1.Wait();
```

No se qué diferencia hay entre la primera opción y las demás, ni si podrá dar error en algún caso, pero de momento parece que sirve.

Answer (score 2):

No puedes llamar a un metodo asincrono como si fuera sincrono. Pero lo puedes encapsular para que se ejecuta de forma sincrona, aún que por dentro sea asincrona. Por ejemplo lo puedes hacer asi (Solución 1):

```
var task = streamCont.ReadAsMultipartAsync(provider);
var result = task.WaitAndUnwrapException(); // En este momento se ejecuta y no pasa a la siguiente linea hasta que finaliza ejecución. Si no tiene resultado, le puese quitar "var result"
```

Solución 2:

```
var result = AsyncContext.RunTask(ReadAsMultipartAsync).Result;
```

Solución 3:

```
var result = AsyncContext.Run(ReadAsMultipartAsync);
```

Solución 4:

```
public async Task<int> MyAsyncTask(int x)
{
    return await Task.FromResult(x + 1);
}

public void MyNormalTask()
{
    // Option 4
    var task = MyAsyncTask(x: 10);
    task.Wait();
    int myresult = task.Result;
    Debug.WriteLine($"Task result: {myresult}");
}
```

Comment: Gracias, pero no tengo la función "WaitAndUnwrapException". 
Para el "AsyncContext" tengo que añadir la libreria "Nito.AsyncEx" que no se de dónde viene. Para poder tener la función "ReadAsMultipartAsync" ya he tenido que añadir la librería "System.Net.Http.Formatting", y me resulta muy extraño tener que agregar otra más, cuando lo que quiero hacer es un "split" de un texto (un texto un poco especial). Tampoco entiendo porqué todas las funciones son asíncronas...
Gracias de nuevo!

Comment: Bueno. Mira, aqui tienes otra opción. Quizas esta te gusta mas y no necesitas tantas librerias. Lo he puesto como opción 4